# Can't Access XML variable in PHP from Flash?

Tags: php, xml, actionscript-3, flash

I am sending some information from PHP to flash, and sending some different information from PHP back to flash. I'm sending a user ID to PHP, and sending an XML variable, as well as an index, back to Flash.

Flash code:

```
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
  var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(/*private info*/);
  myRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
  var memberInfo:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
  memberInfo.member_id = 1817;
  myRequest.data = memberInfo;
  myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXMLLoad);
  myLoader.load(myRequest);

  function onXMLLoad(event:Event)
  {
    var newXML:XML = new XML(event.currentTarget.data.xml);
    var index:int = new int(event.currentTarget.data.index);
  }
```

PHP:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$presets = $xml->createElement("presets");
$red = $xml->createElement("colors", "0xff0000");
$green = $xml->createElement("colors", "0x00ff00");
$blue = $xml->createElement("colors", "0x0000ff");

$presets->appendChild($red);
$presets->appendChild($green);
$presets->appendChild($blue);
$xml->appendChild($presets);

$index = 3;

echo $xml->saveXML();
echo $index;
```

When I do this, I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property xml not found on String and there is no default value.
```

How can I fix this? I'm thinking it has something to do with the XML actually being a string, but I'm not quite sure.

Here is the output from PHP:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<presets>
    <colors>0xff0000</colors>
    <colors>0x00ff00</colors>
    <colors>0x0000ff</colors>
</presets> 3
```

**Note:**
If I delete the index variable from PHP and just have "xml" as the only thing being sent to Flash, I can access it using "event.currentTarget.data" and it will work fine.

Flash:

```
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
  var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(/*private info*/);
  myRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
  var memberInfo:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
  memberInfo.member_id = 1817;
  myRequest.data = memberInfo;
  myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXMLLoad);
  myLoader.load(myRequest);

  function onXMLLoad(event:Event)
  {
    var newXML:XML = new XML(event.currentTarget.data);
  }
```

PHP:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$presets = $xml->createElement("presets");
$red = $xml->createElement("colors", "0xff0000");
$green = $xml->createElement("colors", "0x00ff00");
$blue = $xml->createElement("colors", "0x0000ff");

$presets->appendChild($red);
$presets->appendChild($green);
$presets->appendChild($blue);
$xml->appendChild($presets);
echo $xml->saveXML();
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the php header as xml? `header( "content-type: application/xml; charset=ISO-8859-15" );`

Comment: Just tried this, as well as     header( "content-type: text/xml"), both generated the same error as before :(

Comment: can you show the actuall output from the php action?  Likely your getting something like this:  `<xml></xml>3`, which is not valid xml and does not have an `xml` url parameter as AS3 is expecting something like this: `xml=<xml></xml>&index=3`

Comment: There is no output in Flash from the php action except for the ReferenceError. When I use `event.currentTarget.data`, and `xml` is the only thing being echoed, the xml is outputted and well-formatted in flash.

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis:  `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<presets>
  <colors>0xff0000</colors>
  <colors>0x00ff00</colors>
  <colors>0x0000ff</colors>
</presets>
3' is what is outputted when I use .TEXT. When I create a new set of URLVariables inside my onComplete function, and access the `.xml` property of the new URLVariables, I get null as my output. (Sorry, the xml in my comment is well-formed in the output)

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis I tried .VARIABLES originally, still the same error...so confused as to why this is happening. I'm using the `header( "content-type: application/xml; charset=ISO-8859-15" );` header in my PHP file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your output from PHP.

The output shown, is not valid xml (because of the `3` at the end).

That is why it works when you remove the index.

To rectify it, either put the index in the xml (as an attribute to the root `presets` node perhaps), or parse the output prior to converting it to an XML object in AS3, like so:

```
        var response:String = event.currentTarget.data;
        var index:String = response.substr(response.lastIndexOf(">") + 1);
        var newXML:XML = new XML(response.substring(0, response.lastIndexOf(">") + 1));
```

If you want to be able to access variables as objects on the data property (eg like `event.currentTarget.data.xml` & `event.currentTarget.data.index`, then you need to do the following:

1. Set the `dataFormat` property of the URLLoader to `URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES`, so it knows how to parse the response as such.
2. Send from PHP a url variable formatted string.  So your response from php would need to look like the following:

   ```
   xml=<xml></xml>&index=3
   ```

   Where `<xml></xml>` is replaced with your full xml.  Keep in mind, all data will need to follow the url variable formatting rules, so you may need to use `escape` (or `rawurlencode` in PHP) and `unescape`(in AS3) on the values

   here is what I think the php should look like:

   ```
   echo "xml=".$xml->saveXML(); 
   echo "&index=".$index;
   ```

---

Easier though, may be to just use JSON and create an object in PHP and do `echo json_encode(obj)`,  then in flash do `var response:Object = JSON.parse(event.currentTarget.data);`

Comment: So maybe I'm mis-interpreting the usage of `loader.data` in flash. If I have two variables that I want to send from PHP to Flash, one being an XML object (xml) and one being an integer (index), can I not access these elements separately via Flash? (i.e. `event.currentTarget.data.xml`, `event.currentTarget.data.index`). Am I only limited to accessing `loader.data` as a whole?

Comment: Thank you. I recall now seeing things like this. Would I echo this from PHP in a way similar to `echo "$xml=$xml->saveXML()";` ?

Comment: yes, and then use the ampersand between any subsequent parameters.  I haven't actually used PHP though in about a decade so I'm quite rusty there.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's still not working but I think this a step in the right direction, and I can hopefully figure out where to go from here.

Comment: It's working for me with the string: `xml=<?xml version="1.0"?><presets><colors>0xff0000</colors><colors>0x00ff00</colors><colors>0x0000ff</colors></presets>&index=3` .  Unfortunately I can't help too much with the PHP side

Comment: `echo "xml=".$xml->saveXML();` `echo "&index=".$index;`  I think should be your php